# How can I swap colors with GIMP?

Tags: colors, gimp

I have made an image with three colors: RGB

I want to swap each channel to a specific color. Is there a way to do that efficiently with GIMP?

**Example:**

[image]

I would like:

- **Blue**: #434343
- **Red**: #EEEEEE
- **Green**: #BBBBBB

Answer (score 63):

For GIMP 2.6.12, Just use `Colors -> Map -> Color Exchange`

Comment: This solution works, but what if we want to keep gradient border ?

Comment: Is it normal that there is still a bit of black borders remaining in a barcode? Any solution to get it completely blue? I want it blue because my printer only has the blue cartridge working correctly so the printing is more visible when printing blue.

Answer (score 13):

Try `Filters -> Colors -> Map -> Color Exchange...` in RGB mode.

You should be able to replace one color with another easily.

Comment: Seems so promising but doesn't seem to work if the color you're swapping out is transparent (alpha = 0).

Comment: What if we want to preserve a gradient? I have white text on a colored background and I would like to replace it with colored text on a white background.

Answer (score 9):

To directly modify how each channel is interpreted, use `Colors -> Components -> Channel Mixer`.

To get what you want, you would select

- **Blue:**

  - Red: 26.3
  - Green: 26.3
  - Blue: 26.3
- **Red:**

  - Red: 93.3
  - Green: 93.3
  - Blue: 93.3
- **Green:**

  - Red: 73.3
  - Green: 73.3
  - Blue: 73.3

Comment: This solution is the only one working, by changing gradient borders as well. Sadly most of the time, we just want to choose the destination color by using the hex code. Any idea to do that ?